Excute all batch commands in Windows terminal new-tab(Wt)
I have a bat file containing:
wt -w 0 new-tab node index.js
This code create new tab & excute node index.js (in windwos terminal application)
But i want add several command if script get error, restart again in loop like following code:
:loop
node index.js
timeout /t 10
Goto :loop

But how can add all commands in new-tab
I need a structure like this
wt -w 0 new-tab "
^:loop
^node index.js
^timeout /t 10
^Goto :loop"

but don't work so don't have idea
(I need to excute all my commanda in wt)
